# How to configure logging provider with dependency injection for .NET library

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a typical scenario where I'm developing a .NET Core library and want the calling application to be able to optionally configure the logging options.

Ideally I'd like to use dependency injection on the `ILogger` property of each class in the library. What I can't work out is how to have the DI container is initialised in one assembly, the application executable, and consume it in a different one, the library assembly.

The best I can come up with is the example below where the DI container is initialised in the executing assembly and then stored in an **intermediary** assembly that the library then accesses. My question is whether there's a way to do without the **intermediary** assembly AND avoid the need to pollute the library constructors with a logging instance which may or may not be needed?

In the contrived example below each namespace represents a separate assembly. The library assembly does not know anything about the Application assembly.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;
using Serilog;

namespace MainAssembly
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DI + Log Test");

            // Set up logging factory.
            var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            var serilogConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Is(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug)
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}] ({SourceContext}.{Method}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();
            loggerFactory.AddSerilog(serilogConfig);

            // Set up dependency injection services.
            ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<LoggerFactory>(loggerFactory);
            IntermediaryAssembly.DI.ServicesSingleton = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Attempt to get a logger from the DI container.
            logger = IntermediaryAssembly.DI.TryGetLogger<Program>();

            logger.LogDebug("Logging initialised.");

            var lib = new LibraryAssembly.DoIt();
            lib.DoWork();

            Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        }
    }
}

namespace IntermediaryAssembly
{
    public class DI
    {
        public static ServiceProvider ServicesSingleton;

        public static ILogger<T> TryGetLogger<T>()
        {
            if (ServicesSingleton != null && ServicesSingleton.GetServices<LoggerFactory>().Any())
            {
                return ServicesSingleton.GetRequiredService<LoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                return NullLogger<T>.Instance;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace LibraryAssembly
{
    public class DoIt
    {
        public Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;

        public DoIt()
        {
            // Attempt to get a logger from the DI container.
            logger = IntermediaryAssembly.DI.TryGetLogger<DoIt>();
        }

        public void DoWork()
        {
            logger.LogDebug("Doing work...");
        }
    }
}
```

Packages used:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This is not _Dependency Injection_ it is _Service Location_. This is why you find yourself needing the `IntermediaryAssembly`, to call its service locator. If you were using DI, `LibraryAssembly.DoIt` would not call  `IntermediaryAssembly.DI.TryGetLogger<DoIt>` at all because that wouldn't be its responsibility.

Comment: Right, so how can I use DI across assembly boundaries?

Comment: Well, the consumers of your library have to pass you an `ILogger<DoIt>` or perhaps a logger factory. DI just means parameterization. It the member should not be `static` because it is unclear that instantiating a `DoIt` will cause existing instances to be modified and it breaks testability.

Comment: Ok, got it, I do want to avoid the application having to pass "plumbing" parameters to the library. The `ILogger` member shouldn't have been static, my mistake, I've adjusted that.

Comment: It's hard to judge what is appropriate or would be ergonomic without seeing how `DoIt` would be consumed in a real world scenario. For example, in `MainAssembly`, you could `serviceCollection.AddSingleton<DoIt>();`, modify `DoIt`'s ctor to `public DoIt(ILogger<DoIt> logger) => this.logger = logger;`. But it's hard to know if that would be appropriate.

Comment: If `DoIt` uses DI, then `DoIt` itself needs to be in the same container. Having `ILogger` on the constructor of `DoIt` does not mean the class is polluted. It means the `DoIt` class needs a logger instance, and the logger instance is provided, in this case, by DI container. Otherwise, if the `DoIt` does not use/know DI, then you should forget about DI when in `DoIt`. All you know is an ambient logger or logger factory that comes from say `LoggerFactory.Current`, and the implementation of `LoggerFactory.Current` might be backed by DI like what you already got.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the mistake you are making is simply not resolving the class the logger is being injected into.  you need to make sure that in the startup file, you configure Logging for service injection:

```
services.AddLogging();
```

And in the class you are injecting, just do basic constructor injection, typing ILogger to the hosting class:

```
private readonly ILogger<DoIt> _logger;

public DoIt(ILogger<DoIt> logger)
{
   _logger = logger;
}
```